# Generic struct over a generic type without type parameter

Tags: generics, rust, higher-kinded-types

Is it possible to do something like this in Rust?

```
trait Foo<T> {}

struct A;
struct B;

struct Bar<T: Foo> {
    a: T<A>,
    b: T<B>
}
```

I know I could just use two parameters for `Bar`, but I think there has to be a better way to do this.

I want to implement a `Graph` structure. As I can't just bind the nodes and edges to their parents lifetime, I want to have something like `Rc`. However, sometimes one may need a `Graph` with access from multiple threads. So I'd have to have both an implementation with `Rc` and `Arc`.

That's what `Foo` is good for: I implement `Foo` for both `Rc` and `Arc` (`Foo` would require `Deref`) and I use a parameter `T` bound to `Foo`. That's how I wanted to have one struct for single thread and multi thread usage.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use *generic associated types* (GATs) and the family pattern for that:

```
trait Family {
    type Container<T>;
}

struct A;
struct B;

struct Bar<T: Family> {
    a: T::Container<A>,
    b: T::Container<B>,
}
```

Then you can define two families:

```
struct BoxFamily;
impl Family for BoxFamily {
    type Container<T> = Box<T>;
}

struct VecFamily;
impl Family for VecFamily {
    type Container<T> = Vec<T>;
}
```

And use it:

```
let boxes: Bar<BoxFamily> = Bar {
    a: Box::new(A),
    b: Box::new(B),
};

let vecs: Bar<VecFamily> = Bar {
    a: vec![A, A],
    b: vec![B],
};
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=49a2ce621940c3ec074264bc8663e3e3))

As you can see, it's slightly more involved than one would hope for: you can't just say `Bar<Vec>` for example, but have to go through the extra family type. But it works!

For an older answer (before GATs existed) containing more general information about the topic, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41509242/6).

Comment: thanks for such a long answer! Very interesting. Only the `for` syntax seems a bit confusing to me but I will definitely read the chapter about it

Comment: Thanks. Explains the issue well enough. I think the real power comes from type omission of associated types.

Answer (score 8):

In a way Rust *does* have what looks a lot like HKT (see Lukas's answer for a good description of what they are), though with some arguably awkward syntax.

First, you need to define the interface for the pointer type you want, which can be done using a generic trait.  For example:

```
trait SharedPointer<T>: Clone {
    fn new(v: T) -> Self;
    // more, eg: fn get(&self) -> &T;
}
```

Plus a generic trait which defines an associated type which is the type you really want, which must implement your interface:

```
trait Param<T> {
    type Pointer: SharedPointer<T>;
}
```

Next, we implement that interface for the types we're interested in:

```
impl<T> SharedPointer<T> for Rc<T> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Self {
        Rc::new(v)
    }
}
impl<T> SharedPointer<T> for Arc<T> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Self {
        Arc::new(v)
    }
}
```

And define some dummy types which implement the `Param` trait above.  This is the key part; we can have one type (`RcParam`) which implements `Param<T>` for any `T`, including being able to supply a type, which means we're simulating a higher-kinded type.

```
struct RcParam;
struct ArcParam;

impl<T> Param<T> for RcParam {
    type Pointer = Rc<T>;
}

impl<T> Param<T> for ArcParam {
    type Pointer = Arc<T>;
}
```

And finally we can use it:

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct Foo<P: Param<A> + Param<B>> {
    a: <P as Param<A>>::Pointer,
    b: <P as Param<B>>::Pointer,
}

impl<P: Param<A> + Param<B>> Foo<P> {
    fn new(a: A, b: B) -> Foo<P> {
        Foo {
            a: <P as Param<A>>::Pointer::new(a),
            b: <P as Param<B>>::Pointer::new(b),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Look ma, we're using a generic smart pointer type!
    let foo = Foo::<RcParam>::new(A, B);
    let afoo = Foo::<ArcParam>::new(A, B);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=081b3883b50e15ecd5f0c4e7eef09f49&version=stable&backtrace=0)