# Receiving callbacks with `impl Trait` and passing them existential values

Tags: callback, rust

When defining an API for handler callbacks (e.g. processing shell commands or network requests), I'd like to hide implementation details from the callback signature -- for example, I'd like to accept callbacks of the form

```
fn c(data: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) -> ()
```

While I can easily express the callbacks themselves using the `impl Trait` argument syntax or as `fn c<I: Iterator<...>>(data: I) -> ()`, I can't accept them that generically because my processor is not universal on `I`, but existential.

I could make the processing parts generic on `I` and then say that `I: Iterator<Item = i32>`:

```
/// A non-working callback that receives an iterator.
use std::iter::*;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Processor<CB, I> {
    callback: CB,
    _i: PhantomData<I>,
}

// Here it'd be nice to say that it won't implement it for all I, but there exists an (unnamable) I
// for which it's implemented.
impl<CB, I> Processor<CB, I>
where
    CB: FnMut(I) -> (),
    I: Iterator<Item = i32>,
{
    fn process(self) {
        let a = [23, 42].iter().map(|i| i + 1);
        let mut cb = self.callback;
        cb(a)
    }
}

fn c(data: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) {
    println!("Data:");
    for i in data {
        println!("Item: {}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Processor {
        callback: c,
        _i: PhantomData,
    };
    p.process()
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=4b3fa08c29a86295c88ad6f68d5e342e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This is not true as the implementation is not generic on `I` and the compiler expresses its dissatisfaction with the lie:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:12
   |
20 |         cb(a)
   |            ^ expected type parameter, found struct `std::iter::Map`
   |
   = note: expected type `I`
              found type `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:18:37: 18:46]>`
```

I also tried to name the unnameable as far as possible, but that generates really unwieldy type names (workable in the example, but resulting in multi-line type names in practical code):

```
/// A non-working callback that receives an iterator.
use std::iter::*;

struct Processor<CB> {
    callback: CB,
}

impl<CB> Processor<CB>
where
    CB: FnMut(Map<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>, FnOnce(i32) -> i32>) -> (),
{
    fn process(self) {
        let a = [23, 42].iter().map(|i| i + 1);
        let mut cb = self.callback;
        cb(a)
    }
}

fn c(data: impl Iterator<Item = i32>) {
    println!("Data:");
    for i in data {
        println!("Item: {}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Processor { callback: c };
    p.process()
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=98fc2a882a89553e6fb1f5d2c1020bf1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This still fails once there is a lambda type involved:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(i32) -> i32 + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:8:1
   |
8  | / impl<CB> Processor<CB>
9  | | where
10 | |     CB: FnMut(Map<std::slice::Iter<'static, i32>, FnOnce(i32) -> i32>) -> (),
11 | | {
...  |
16 | |     }
17 | | }
   | |_^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(i32) -> i32 + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-sized>
   = note: required by `std::iter::Map`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(i32) -> i32 + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
12 | /     fn process(self) {
13 | |         let a = [23, 42].iter().map(|i| i + 1);
14 | |         let mut cb = self.callback;
15 | |         cb(a)
16 | |     }
   | |_____^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(i32) -> i32 + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-sized>
   = note: required by `std::iter::Map`
```

What's the idiomatic way around this? Is it possible with a different syntax that says "For all `CB` this implements `Processor`, where the `CB` type needs to be generic on its argument and I get to choose its type"? Something like

```
impl<CB> Processor<CB>
where
    CB: FnMut(impl Iterator<Item = i32>) -> (),
```

Given that I am aiming for an embedded environment, I'm looking for solutions that do not involve std, so approaches like `Box<...>` won't solve the issue.

Comment: PS: The same can be asked about lifetimes as well ("The callback needs to be generic on an `'a` in its `&'a [u8]` argument, but my processor picks the lifetime and it will only barely outlive the callback invocation") -- I've run into both versions, but to the type system they're probably the same, and I'd only continue with the lifetime version of the problem once the unnamable-closure version is resolved.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Generic struct over a generic type without type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41508680/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I'm guessing you wouldn't find it satisfactory to change the signature to `fn c(data: Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i32>>) `...

Comment: @Shepmaster, the RFC that answers the other question is not (directly) helpful here, but helped me find an answer (in progress). Thanks for the link and the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my issue was introducing a trait for callbacks that has a workhorse method that's generic on an argument's type. This precludes the direct use of lambdas as callbacks AFAICT (I can't wrap them), but allows passing around functions generic on their argument types or lifetimes.

The punchline is the trait function

```
fn call_now<T: Iterator<Item=i32>>(&mut self, data: T) -> ();
```

, and the full adapted code example goes like this:

```
use std::iter::*;

trait Callback {
    fn call_now<T: Iterator<Item=i32>>(&mut self, data: T) -> ();
}

struct Processor<CB>
{
    callback: CB
}

impl<CB: Callback> Processor<CB> where
{
    fn process(&mut self) {
        let a = [23, 42].iter().map(|i| i + 1);
        self.callback.call_now(a);
    }
}

struct C();
impl Callback for C {
    fn call_now<T: Iterator<Item=i32>>(&mut self, data: T) {
        println!("Data:");
        for i in data {
            println!("Item: {}", i);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Processor {
        callback: C(),
    };
    p.process()
}
```

([try on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9b35fda51e39d4a792589372b129bdc7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Higher-kind types ([as explained well in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508680/generic-struct-over-a-generic-type-without-type-parameter)), which have been suggested as a solution, helped understand the problem, but seem not to be directly applicable. (They might help wrapping lambdas, but I'm not sure of that.)

Comment: I think that on current nightlies [using type_alias_impl_trait could be part of a simpler solution](https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7903137fb906795fd4047dfde0d2402); I'll need to go through how far this can be used to solve the original problem statement.